# How to change the system date and time into correct time zone

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, timezone

I have two fields,

**CreatedDate**

**UpdatedDate**

It takes from the system date and time.. My sql server is located at UK. So when i see in site it is showing wrong time.. how to change this in mvc?

My details page, i am showing like following,

```
 <strong>Date Posted:</strong>
            <%:Model.CreatedDate%>
```

Please give me the ideas?

Comment: Start here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

I would store your dates using UTC and then use that as a baseline for converting to the appropriate timezone for your region. This makes it flexible since you have a constant reference point.

Comment: how to use UTC time? I am not familiar with this? can u give me some example?